# How to fix the left and right margin in plot_objective function from skopt.plots?

Tags: matplotlib, xgboost

See this plot_objective:
[image]

It was obtained by:

```
fig=plt.figure(num="HPO_plot_objective",figsize=(10,10))
plot_objective(result=optimize_result,n_points=n_calls)
```

the `num_boost_round` (on the left), and the eta (at the bottom, first column), is hidden by the margin. How to fix that?

I tried to play with margins in this way, but there is no effect

```
fig=plt.figure(num="HPO_plot_objective",figsize=(10,10))
plot_objective(result=optimize_result,n_points=n_calls)
plt.margins(1.0,1.0)
plt.savefig(f"results/plot_objective.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

`plt.tight_layout()` may fix the problem.

Comment: no, unfortunately, I had tried that and it had no impact.